# Insert array of numbers into a single column , MySQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random

So what I am trying that I am creating an array of 500 random numbers, and trying to send them into the database.

But Every time I run the program only 1 value gets inserted in the database and that value is `0`.

The query runs successfully but the data won't get inserted.

Here is what I have tried.

**Create a list of 500 random numbers:**

```
$data = [] ;

for($i=0; $i<500; $i++)
 {
  $data[] = rand(0,10);  
 }

$into_mysql = json_encode($data);
```

**Query to send the data in the MySQL table:**

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO points(value) VALUES ('$into_mysql')";

  mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  echo "\n Data Inserted Successfully";
```

In the output, I am getting `Data Inserted Successfully`. but the database column only gets `0` entry as you can see :

[image]

Please correct me If I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried implode function ??

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman this is one case where that is not true. A straight insert as I describe in my answer will be far more efficient than preparing a statement and executing it 500 times. And given that the only data being inserted is random numbers, there is no possibility of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the output of `json_encode` is something like `"[5, 8, 1 ... , 2]"` which is not a valid integer, so you get a value of `0` inserted. What you need to do is generate 500 inserts, which you can do using [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to generate the separate values:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO points(value) VALUES (" . implode('),(', $data) . ")";
```